# Derivative of matrix to vector then multiply with another vector

Tags: matrices, derivatives, vector-analysis

I'd like to know if I have a Matrix $\textbf{A} \in \Re^{n\times n} $ and a vector $\vec{b}\in \Re^{n\times 1}$ , and they are irrelevant to each other. $\textbf{A} = \textbf{A}(\vec{x})$ is the function of vector $\vec{x} \in \Re^{n \times 1}$, and $\vec{b}$ is irrelevant with $\vec{x}$, then does the formula below hold?

$$
(\frac{d \textbf{A}}{d \vec{x}})\vec{b} = \frac{d (\textbf{A} \vec{b})}{d \vec{x}}
$$

Which turns an order-3 tensor derivative $\frac{d \textbf{A}}{d \vec{x}}$  multiplying with a vector $\vec{b}$ into the derivative of a vector $\textbf{A} \vec{b}$ to vector $\vec{x}$, which is easier to compute.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on what you mean by $d\mathbf A/\vec x$. Consider that in index notation the derivative of $A$ is $\partial_i A^j_k$. There are then two natural ways to multiply by $\vec b$:
$$
  \partial_i A^j_kb^i\quad\text{or}\quad\partial_iA^j_kb^k.
$$
It is only the second one where we can say $(d\mathbf A/d\vec x)\vec b = d(\mathbf A\vec b)/d\vec x$. Generally, the $d/d\vec x$ notation is not nuanced enough to properly deal with derivatives of tensors.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! Does the index notation $\partial_i A^j_{k}$ means the derivative A[j,k] ($j^{th}$ row, $k^{th}$ column) with respect to the $i^{th}$ entry of $\vec{x}$? If so, the multiplication in my problem is $\partial_i A^j_{k} b^k$

Comment: @ZhehaoLi Yes, correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Then in my problem, the proposed formula is correct. I need to learn more about index notation to deal with tensor derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

The following formula for the *differential* of a product
$$d\big(A\star B\big) = dA\star B \;+\; A\star dB$$
holds for tensors of ***any*** order (scalars, vectors, matrices, etc) and for ***any*** kind of product (dot, double-dot, cross, dyadic, Hadamard, Kronecker, etc) with which the tensors are dimensionally compatible.

Applying this to your problem (written with an explicit dot product) yields
$$\eqalign{
\def\p{\partial}
\def\n{\nabla}
\def\g#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
d(A\cdot b) &= dA\cdot b \qquad \big(db\;{\rm is\:zero}\big) \\
}$$
If the gradient operation is defined as
$$\eqalign{
\left(\n w\right)_{ij} &= \g{w_{j}}{x_i}
 \quad\implies\quad dw=dx\cdot\n w
}$$
then expanding the previous differential expression yields the proposed formula
$$\eqalign{
dx\cdot\n(A\cdot b) &= dx\cdot\n A\cdot b \\
\n(A\cdot b) &= \n A\cdot b \\
}$$
However, if your gradient operator is defined with components in the transposed order, then the proposed formula will be false (as Nicholas stated in his answer). But in that case, you could just transpose the whole equation
$$\n(b^T\cdot A^T) = b^T\cdot\n A^T$$

Comment: Thanks for your informative answer!